# Accessing M-files API from Perl

Tags: .net, windows, perl, vba, ole

I am trying to access the M-Files API (M-Files is a document management system) from a Perl script. I wish to copy a template M-Files view and create a new one with appropriate filters.

The M-Files API can be accessed from C#, VB.NET, VBA such as Excel, etc. As I wish to use Perl, is the Perl Win32::OLE module the correct starting point?

Do you know of a way I can write Perl to access the Windows and M-Files object space ? I wish to do stuff like creating a new M-Files API Search Criteria as per the following line of VBA code:

```
Dim oSearchCriteria As New MFilesAPI.SearchCriteria
```

I know how to access Windows functions from Perl, but what Perl packages do I need to instantiate a

Comment: Please post a short but complete example in C# or VB.NET or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with M-Files, but yes, [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) is probably the way to go.  Try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;

my $oSearchCriteria =  Win32::OLE->new('MFilesAPI.SearchCriteria')
  or die "Failed to initialize MFilesAPI.SearchCriteria";

# Methods use Perl method call syntax:
$oSearchCriteria->SomeMethod('some parameter');

# Properties use hash syntax:
my $prop = $oSearchCriteria->{SomeProperty};
$oSearchCriteria->{OtherProperty} = 'new value for property';
```